# Need code to get all files in directory and past another local?

Tags: python

i need code python to get all pic  files in diretorie e paste another dir
for ex.
in "c:\capture" confirm exist pic files, if true get all and paste in c:\backup\paste.1
sleep 30 min and confirm new files in c:\capture if true get all and past in c:\backup\paste.2

sorry my bad english
tks

Comment: This website works best if you have a current solution in place that is not working, you can ask us for *help*, but you cannot assume that when you ask for code you'll be given one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, by are you looking for [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir), [`os.rename()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) and the other functions of the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module?

The [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module might also be useful, depending on the specifics of what you want to do.